# Aggregate to Create Groups of Documents by Size

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mapreduce, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection called "orders". Each order in this collection has an array of product ids. For example:

```
> db.orders.find()
[
  { _id: 1, products: [10, 11, 12] },
  { _id: 2, products: [13, 14] },
  { _id: 3, products: [15] },
  { _id: 4, products: [16, 17] }
]
```

Now, I want to create a collection where I group up to `n` products, where every order's products must be in the same document, and n will always be greater than the number of products in any order.

so, in the example above, say I specified `n` as 3. The result would look like:

```
[{
  orders: [1],
  products: [10, 11, 12]
}, {
  orders: [2, 3],
  products: [13, 14, 15]
}, {
  orders: [4],
  products: [16, 17]
}]
```

Is this possible with a mongo aggregation?

Answer (score 1):

This actually isn't something you would do in array aggregation process really. It simply is not possible in the aggregation framework since you need to maintain values across documents. There is no natural grouping boundary other than a "tipping point" where the total collected elements for `"products"` becomes *three or more* values, and that sort of accumulation requires "globals", which is something that is not available to the aggregation framework.

MapReduce has "globals", but when you consider the operations involved, this does not "reduce" anything. Sure there is "accumulation", but that is only a factor of the total data processed to that "tipping point" as mentioned above. The actual data returned is *"exactly the same"* as the data stored in the collection, but just *re-organized* in output format.

As such, accumulation across documents is best handled in processing a "cursor". So expanding on your sample data with a few more items to illustrate another point:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "products" : [ 10, 11, 12 ] }
{ "_id" : 2, "products" : [ 13, 14 ] }
{ "_id" : 3, "products" : [ 15 ] }
{ "_id" : 4, "products" : [ 16, 17 ] }
{ "_id" : 5, "products" : [ 18, 19 ] }
{ "_id" : 6, "products" : [ 20, 21 ] }
{ "_id" : 7, "products" : [ 22, 23 ] }
```

You then are basically processing the "cursor" results with logic to do the accumulation:

```
var output = {}

db.orders.find().forEach(function(order) {
  if ( !output.hasOwnProperty("_id") ) {
    output = { "_id": [order._id], products: [] };
  } else {
    output._id = output._id.concat([order._id]);
  }
  output.products = output.products.concat(order.products);

  if ( output.products.length > 3 ) {
    var hold = {};
    hold._id = output._id.slice(-1);
    hold.products = output.products.slice(-(output.products.length-3));
    output.products = output.products.slice(0,3);
    printjson(output);
    output = hold;
  } else if ( output.products.length == 3) {
    printjson(output)
    output = {};
  }
})

if ( Object.keys(output).length != 0 ) {
  printjson(output);
}
```

Which would output as:

```
{ "_id" : [ 1 ], "products" : [ 10, 11, 12 ] }
{ "_id" : [ 2, 3 ], "products" : [ 13, 14, 15 ] }
{ "_id" : [ 4, 5 ], "products" : [ 16, 17, 18 ] }
{ "_id" : [ 5, 6 ], "products" : [ 19, 20, 21 ] }
{ "_id" : [ 7 ], "products" : [ 22, 23 ] }
```

So the output is in a different "format" and "accumulated" so that all `"products"` data has at most *three* items present, but it still in fact *the very same data in the collection, **without reduction***. That is the important point here.

The process of accumulation therefore requires the *"global"*, where you build up the list of accumulated `_id` values as well as the total `products`. Note also that since the data accumulated for `[4,5]` would actually exceed the *three* items, the remaining item(s) would then be carried over into the next "grouping".

Now mapReduce does have *"globals"* as mentioned earlier, but this sort of accumulation across documents means that there *generally* will be something left over that did not "emit" because the total `"products"` did not yet reach the count of *three*.

And the case with mapReduce would really just be as a *JavaScript runnner* on the server, since again this accumlation is actually done in the "mapper" function rather than the "reducer". The function of a "reducer" requires the "grouping key" to already be determined in the mapper. So it's the mappers job to do the global accumlation to get the `_id` combinations.

Not to mention that in "collection" output, MongoDB does not like "arrays" for `_id` values, and will in fact "error" if you try.

So this is not really a job for *"server aggregation"*, but instead the natrual work is really done here by processing a "cursor". It's *"all of the original data anyway"* so it's not like running on the server *reduced* the output of data returned. Process the cursor.